# schemagen ant task ignores package-info.java

Tags: ant, jaxb, jaxb2, schemagen

The scenario is the following: I have a java package (*myapp.config*) that contains all my JAXB-annotated classes, from which I'd like to generate an XML schema file. In the package, there is also a *package-info.java* file, which contains the *@XmlSchema* annotation on the package element, thus valid in the whole package:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace="http://myapp/config",
           xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix="myapp", namespaceURI="http://myapp/config"),
           elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package myapp.config;
```

When I run the *schemagen* command-line tool that comes with the JDK,

```
D:\Projects\Myapp>"%JAVA_HOME%/bin/schemagen" -cp "%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar"
src/myapp/config/*.java
```

I get the correct result: the root element in the generated *schema1.xsd* file contains the *targetNamespace* and other necessary attributes:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
           targetNamespace="http://myapp/config"
           xmlns:tns="http://myapp/config"
           xmlns:myapp="http://myapp/config">
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
```

However, when I want to perform the same task within my Ant script,

```
<schemagen srcdir="src/myapp/config" destdir="dist">
    <include name="*.java"/>
</schemagen>
```

The schemagen tool seems to completely ignore the namespace annotations, because in the resulting *schema1.xsd* file, there is no trace of them:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

When I run the *schemagen* task in *verbose* and *debug* mode, it becomes obvious that the tool does load all the *.java* files, except *package-info.java*, that's why it doesn't know anything about the namespaces.

Have you met this strange behavior before? Why the command-line tool processes the package info file, and the Ant task doesn't? What should I do to make the Ant task work?

Thanks in advance,
buc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately I found the solution, I post it for those who run into the same problem in the future:

The reason it did not work is that I called the *schemagen* task in the wrong way (this can happen, if there is so little documentation or examples as in the case of schemagen).
Instead of writing:

```
<schemagen srcdir="src/myapp/config" destdir="dist">
    <include name="*.java"/>
</schemagen>
```

You should move the specific part of the path into the *include* element:

```
<schemagen srcdir="src" destdir="dist">
    <include name="myapp/config/*.java"/>
</schemagen>
```

I'm still not sure why this is happening, but this way, the schemagen processor recognizes that the *myapp/config* directory in fact designates the java package *myapp.config* and by knowing that it is a package, it will also read the package info file.

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar path problem with the mojo jaxb-2 maven plugin... it required me to include "**/*.java" instead of a more specific path "src/my/path/*.java", which not only didn't work, but it produced no errors. This post is the only reason I even considered that the path might be the problem.